# How to kickstart developmentof iPhone app?

Tags: macos

I just got myself a MacBook air and like to ask what should I do to get started developing iPhone application?

1. Signup for apple developer program. Do I need to pay $99 for this? And exact steps I can folllow?
2. Install Xcode? And start development? What about database what kind of database iPhone app is using?
3. Does Mac os x allow multiple user access? Meaning can another user remotely access through ssh e.g.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, when you're sure you want try your programs in real phone.
2. Yes, mandatory. Read something about CoreData
3. Yes, you only have to activate the remote access